# Custom Shuffle Method Encountering Unexpected kDO_COND

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a custom shuffle method as a training exercise. The goal is to take an array as input, then spit out a new one with all the values shuffled randomly. It seems like I got the gist of the code down, but for some reason I keep getting the message: "unexpected kDO_COND, expecting kEND , array.each do ^ |item|". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
def shuffle(array)
  shuf = []

  while array.length > 0
    randIndex = rand(array.length)
    currentIndex = 0
    newArray = []
    array.each do |item|
      if randIndex == currentIndex
        shuf.push(item)
      else
        newArray.push(item)
      end
      currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
    end
      array = newArray
    end
  shuf
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the code correctly? Works for me.

Comment: Had to clear the cache...works now. Whoops

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone who stumbles in here looking for a quick shuffle:

```
def shuffle(arr)
  arr.sort_by{ rand }
end

p(shuffle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
```